# Trying to create a form where I can update a record which has been searched upon

Tags: c#

I have created a form where I can search for a record in an access database and then choose to archive however I cannot seem to get the update script to actually update the record which has been returned in the query above.

Can someone help?

Thanks

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data     Source=BoilerSvc_be.mdb";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Archived = 0 AND (Surname = '" + textBox3.Text + "' OR Initial = '" + textBox3.Text + "' OR [Post Town] = '" + textBox3.Text + "' OR [Post Code] = '" + textBox3 + "')", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Name", textBox3));
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            LoopThroughRecs(reader);
            // Insert code to process data.
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    private void LoopThroughRecs(OleDbDataReader Data)
    {
        if (Data.Read())
        {
            customid.Text = Data["CustID"].ToString();
            FirstName.Text = Data["Initial"].ToString();
            LastName.Text = Data["Surname"].ToString();
            Address1.Text = Data["Address 1"].ToString();
            Address2.Text = Data["Address 2"].ToString();
            Address3.Text = Data["Address 3"].ToString();
            TownCity.Text = Data["Post Town"].ToString();
            PostCode.Text = Data["Post Code"].ToString();
            Telephone.Text = Data["Telephone"].ToString();
        }

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=BoilerSvc_be.mdb";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblContacts SET Archived = 1 WHERE CustID = "CustID");
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ID", customid));
        }
        finally
        {
            customid.Text = null;
            FirstName.Text = null;
            LastName.Text = null;
            Address1.Text = null;
            Address2.Text = null;
            Address3.Text = null;
            TownCity.Text = null;
            PostCode.Text = null;
            Telephone.Text = null;
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Customer Archived");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your update command seems to be incorrect. Try this instead:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblContacts SET Archived = 1 WHERE CustID = @ID");
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ID", customid));
```

Also try to use parameters with your `select` statement also to avoid SQL Injection:

```
"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Archived = 0 AND (Surname = @Name OR..."
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Name", textBox3.Text));
//And also for other
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Unfortunately that still isn't working - It won't return any values on the search box now either

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` on your Update.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblContacts SET Archived = 1 WHERE CustID = @ID");
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ID", customid));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```